# multiprocessing: dictionary is not persistent

Tags: python, parallel-processing, process, synchronization, shared-memory

I am using processes to run different functions inside a loop multiple times. Each function should return an output on each iteration, which is a dictionary. What I am doing currently is to create a global index dictionary of lists and append each output to this index.

In each iteration I see that the resulted dictionary is stored to this index, however after a new set of iterations the results are missing. I thought this happened maybe because the pointer to the list was overwritten through the different processes so I instantiated the index dictionary and then stored the results directly to a specific row in the list (which also failed). How does a new process handles the global objects ? I know that it's not thread which shares memory and each process creates new internal variables however i'm not passing the global index to it.

Shouldn't the process write to the father's memory (by reference)? And why does the global index (dictionary) resets after each new set of iterations and not after the end of each process ?

```
class my_dict(object):
    def __init__(self, increase_cost, max_cost, step):
        self.performance = dict()
        self.weights = dict()
        self.init_arrays(increase_cost, max_cost, step)

def init_arrays(self, increase_cost, max_cost, step):
    for i in range (increase_cost, max_cost+step, step):
        self.performance[i] = [None for k in range(0,31)]
        self.weights[i] = [None for k in range(0,31)]

original = my_dict(increase_cost,max_cost,step)

...
while increase_cost <= max_cost :

    k_fold_iteration = 0
    for iter in range(0,3):
        print "iteration = " + str(iter)
        start = time.time()
        kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=int(time.time()), shuffle=True)
        for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X,y):

            X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
            y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

            process1 = Process(target=train_original_classifier, args=(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, sa_index,p_Group, costs, increase_cost, k_fold_iteration))
            threads.append(process1)
            k_fold_iteration +=1
            process1.start()
            ...

    for process in threads:
        process.join()

def train_original_classifier(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, sa_index,p_Group, costs,  increase_cost, idx):
    ...
    original.performance[increase_cost][idx]= calculate_fairness(X_test, y_test, y_pred_labels, y_pred_probs, sa_index, p_Group)
    print original.performance
```

Output:

```
{0: [None, ...], 1: [None,...], 2: [results, results,...],...}
```

I tried to keep it minimal, however inside the loop I use other functions through processes as well, which also output dictionaries.

Comment: Maybe not an answer to the exact question that you asked, but if I would hate to save the results of long computation to memory. I would want those to persist on disk or in the database maybe. Maybe I would even use the Luigi library which helps you persist the results. This is what I searched for https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=luigi+train+classifier&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english

Comment: Multiprocessing does not share state trivially, it creates multiple independent processes and copies things like global variables.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is it possible to create a shared memory like in C/C++ ? Or sync the insertions of each process to the father's variables ?

Comment: It is possible but nontrivial. Have you read the multiprocessing documentation? There's a whole section on sharing state

Comment: @Leonid The idea of appending the results to a db crossed my mind, however it's the last solution I would try right now

Comment: Serializing to disk in the child processes (even just as json) and then loading the data in the main process is a common pattern. Note, if you are trying to train multiple sklearn models in parallel, I wouldn't hope for performance gains, indeed, you'll often see significant degradation, since sklearn calls already highly parallelized routines.

Comment: I'll try the serialization approach. I'm training multiple (different) independent classifiers and through parallelization I saw a significant boost in terms of execution speed.

Comment: When using multithreading it's very import to use `multiprocessing.Lock` objects to prevent concurrent access to shared objects. Since I see nothing like that in your code, that could very well be at least part of the problem.